unable to run maven project in archlinux
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project : Error while storing the mojo status: /target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

the log contains
  Base:57 - Execution started in before suite

  Base:60 - Initialized extent manager
- Successfully read data sheet from flow
  Base:66 - Highlighting element is set to false
 Base:68 - Getting screenshots for passed  element is set to false

  Browser:69 - Driver
  Browser:75 - chrome
 INFO  Base:75 - `enter code here`
 INFO  Base:76 - driver=null
 ERROR Base:86 - Error in before suite -> null
 ERROR Events:666 - Input must be set
 ERROR Events:329 - Unable to click on `enter code here`
 ERROR `enter code here`- Unable click  button

